# web page displays abnormally on google-chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, google-chrome

The photo slideshow can't display on google-chrome, but it looks perfect on firefox. The code is here:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>xxxxxxx</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="xxxxxxxxx" />
        <meta name="description" content="xxxxxxx, New York" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon"  href="css/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/tn3e/tn3e.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tn3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var tn1 = $('.mygallery').tn3({
                skinDir:"css",
                autoplay:true,
                width:768,
                delay:5000,
                skin:"tn3e", 
                imageClick:"url",
                image:{
                crop:true,
                transitions:[{
                    type:"blinds",
                    duration:300
                    },
                    {
                    type:"grid",
                    duration:160,
                    gridX:9,
                    gridY:7,
                    easing:"easeInCubic",
                    sort:"circle"
                    },{
                    type:"slide",
                    duration:430,
                    easing:"easeInOutExpo"
                    }]
                }          
                });
        });
        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
    <figure class="logo">
      <img src="css/vbccr.jpg" alt="logo" />
    </figure>'
    <div class="nav_example">
      <div class="menu">
        <span>'
          <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">主页<br />Home</a>
              <div class="subs">
                <div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><h3>关于我们<br />About Us</h3>
                      <ul>'
                        <li><a href="#">陈述</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">历史沿革</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">联系我们</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><h3>冯师<br />Feng</h3>
                      <ul>'
                        <li><a href="#">简介</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">寄语</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">主拜<br />Sunday</a>
              <div class="subs">
                <div class="wrp2">
                  <ul>'
                    <li><h3><a href="#">时间地点<br />Time & Location</a></h3></li>
                    <li><h3>师道<br />Sermons</h3>
                      <ul>'
                        <li><a href="#">2012</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2011</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2010</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2009</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2008</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <p class="sep"></p>
                  <ul>
                    <li><h3>人学<br />School</h3>
                      <ul>'
                        <li><a href="#">新班</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">门班</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>

                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(window).load(function() {      
    $("#nav > li > a").click(function () { // binding onclick
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
            $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
            $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
            $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");

            if ($(this).next(".subs").length) {
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected"); // display popup
                $(this).next(".subs").children().slideDown(200);
            }
        }
    });       
});
</script>

        <!-- This is gallery setting -->
        <div class="mygallery">
          <div class="tn3 album">
        <h4>Large Images</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Large Images</div>
        <div class="tn3 thumb">images/114x72/3.jpg</div>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <h4>Hdfae</h4>
            <div class="tn3 description">daa</div>
            <a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/114x72/1.jpg" alt="demo" /></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Isolated</h4>
            <div class="tn3 description">island</div>
            <a href="images/2.jpg"><img src="images/114x72/2.jpg" alt="demo" /></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>Town</h4>
            <div class="tn3 description">Herceg</div>
            <a href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/114x72/3.jpg" alt="demo" /> </a>
          </li>
        </ol>
          </div>
          <div class="tn3 album">
        <h4>Fixed</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Images</div>
        <div class="tn3 thumb">images/114x72/1.jpg</div>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <h4>Wall</h4>
            <div class="tn3 description">Jai</div>
            <a href="images/920x360/6.jpg"><img src="images/114x72/6.jpg" alt="demo" /></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h4>City</h4>
            <div class="tn3 description">Ne</div>
            <a href="images/920x360/7.jpg"><img src="images/114x72/7.jpg" alt="demo" /></a>
          </li>
        </ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

tn3e.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";

.tn3e-gallery {
    position:relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 550px;
    background-color:#c5c5c5;
    background-image: url('grad.jpg');
    background-position:center center;    
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    line-height: normal;
}
.tn3e-image {
    position:absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 920px;
    height: 360px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
/*
.tn3e-full-image {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(40, 40, 40, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(40, 40, 40, 1); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(40, 40, 40, 1); 

} 
*/   
.tn3e-control-bar {
    position:absolute;
    background: url('bg.png') repeat;
    width:243px;
    height:80px;
}
.tn3e-thumbs ul, .tn3e-thumbs li {
    margin: 0;
}
.tn3e-thumbs {
    position:absolute;
    width:920px;
    height:80px;
    bottom:20px;
    left:20px;
    background-image: url('thumb_bg.png');    
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    padding-top:2px;
}
.tn3e-thumb {
    padding: 2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tn3e-thumb-selected {
    cursor:default;
}
.tn3e-thumb img {
    width: 114px;
    height:72px;
}    
.tn3e-next {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('tn3e.png');
    background-position:-20px -3px;
    width: 13px;
    height: 17px;
    right:33px;
    bottom:126px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tn3e-next:hover {
    background-position:-20px -23px;
}
.tn3e-prev {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('tn3e.png');
    background-position:-2px -3px;
    width: 13px;
    height: 17px;
    left:30px;
    bottom:126px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tn3e-prev:hover {
    background-position:-2px -23px;
}
.tn3e-preloader {
    position:absolute;
    width: 22px;
    height: 8px;
    right:5px;
    top:5px;
}
.tn3e-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 64px;
    bottom: 110px;
    width: 832px;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tn3e-image-title {
    font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#3f4146;
    font-size:12px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.tn3e-image-description {
    font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#3f4146;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:10px;
}
.tn3e-timer {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: url('bg.png') repeat;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.tn3e-play {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('tn3e.png');
    background-position:-2px -80px;
    left:94px;
    top:12px;
    width:57px;
    height:57px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tn3e-play:hover {
    background-position:-64px -80px;
}
.tn3e-play-active {
    background-position:-2px -139px;
}
.tn3e-play-active:hover {
    background-position:-64px -139px;
}
.tn3e-show-albums {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('tn3e.png');
    background-position:-35px -39px;
    top:22px;
    left:23px;
    width:37px;
    height:36px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tn3e-show-albums:hover {
    background-position:-76px -39px;
}
.tn3e-fullscreen {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('tn3e.png');
    background-position:-35px -1px;
    top:22px;
    right:23px;
    width:37px;
    height:36px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tn3e-fullscreen:hover {
    background-position:-76px -1px;
}
.tn3e-albums {
    position:absolute;
    width: 920px;
    height: 510px;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-image:url('bg.png');
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); 
}
.tn3e-albums h4 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1.33em;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 34px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #c7c8c9;
}
.tn3e-inalbums {
    position:absolute;
    top: 80px;
    width: 920px;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.tn3e-album {
    position:absolute;
    width: 420px;
    height: 66px;
    background-color:#111111;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size: medium;
}
.tn3e-album-over {
    background-color:#222;
}
.tn3e-album-selected {
    background-color:#cdcdcd;
    color:#111214;
    cursor:default;
}
.tn3e-album-image {
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 1em;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;
}
.tn3e-album-title {
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.tn3e-album-description {
    font-size:0.6em;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tn3e-albums-next {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('tn3e.png');
    background-position:-217px -1px;
    width: 97px;
    height: 37px;
    right:20px;
    bottom:20px;
    cursor:default;
}
.tn3e-albums-next-over {
    background-position:-217px -40px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tn3e-albums-prev {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('tn3e.png');
    background-position:-117px -1px;
    width: 97px;
    height: 37px;
    left:20px;
    bottom:20px;
    cursor:default;
}
.tn3e-albums-prev-over {
    background-position:-117px -40px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tn3e-albums-close {
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('tn3e.png');
    background-position:-125px -80px;
    width: 27px;
    height: 27px;
    right:31px;
    top:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tn3e-albums-close:hover {
    background-position:-155px -80px;
}

/* when javascript is disabled */
.tn3.album, .tn3.album li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:4px;
}
.tn3.album div, .tn3.album li h4, .tn3.album li div{
    display:none;
}
```

style.css:

```
body {
    background:white;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0;
    width: 768px;
    color:#eee;
    font-size:medium;
    font-family:Tahoma,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
.logo {
    padding:inherit;
    margin:inherit;

}
.logo > img {
    width: 768px;
    display:block;
}
.nav_example {
    background:url(navigation_bar.gif) no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    margin:inherit;
    /* border:1px #000 solid; */
    /* border-radius:3px; */
    /* -moz-border-radius:3px; */
    /* -webkit-border-radius:3px; */
}


/* main menu styles */
.menu {
    padding-top:9px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
.menu > span {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10 auto;
}
#nav {
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    /* text-align:left; */
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#nav > li {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
#nav > li > a {
    /* border:1px solid transparent; */
    color:#eee;
    display:block;
    font-size:1.05em;
    padding:3px 10px;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav > li > a:hover {
    color:#fefefe;
    background-color:#d10e15;
    /* border-color:#999 */
}
#nav > li.selected  > a {
    background-color:#d10e15;
    color:#fefefe;
    z-index:0;
}
#nav li div {
    position:relative;
}
#nav li div div {
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    display:none;
    font-size:1em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    z-index:1;
    width:200px;
}
#nav li div div.wrp2 {
    width:400px;
}
#nav .sep {
    left:200px;
    border-left:1px solid #2a2a2a;
    bottom:0;
    height:auto;
    margin:15px 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:1px;
}
#nav li div ul {
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    position:relative;
    width:190px;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}
#nav li div ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#nav li div ul li h3 {
    border-bottom:1px solid #3a3a3a;
    color:#1da0ff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:0.95em;
    margin:8px 0px;
    padding:3px 0px;
}
#nav li div ul li h3 a {
    color:#1da0ff;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li div ul li h3 a:hover{
    background-color:#d10e15;
    color:#fefefe;
}

#nav li ul ul {
    padding:0 0 8px;
}

#nav li ul ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#nav li ul ul li a {
    color:#eee;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    padding:3px 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:0.95em;
}
#nav li ul ul li a:hover{
    background-color:#d10e15;
    color:#fefefe;
}
```

The jquery.min.js is the latest from google. And jquery.tn3.min.js is from:

```
/*!
 * tn3 v1.1.0.28
 * http://tn3gallery.com/
 *
 * License
 * http://tn3gallery.com/license
 *
 * Date: 29 Jul, 2011 16:21:54 +0300
 */
```

And by the way, the favicon can't show in google-chrome either, but successfully in firefox. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Will need more information, like the CSS and maybe a link to the jQuery plugin you're trying to use....
And when you say "can't display", do you mean it doesn't display correctly, or it doesn't display at all?

You're also missing " type="image/x-icon" " for the favicon

The more information we have, the easier it is to help :)

Comment: its better to create fiddle/online demo will be more suitable, by seeing code its not easy to get the problem solve in your situation.

Comment: @HappySingh:That's a good suggestion. The problem is I don't have a online place to do that.

Comment: @Mattisdata: Thanks. I just added css files. It might be too complicated to debug just by looking at them. The whole slideshow just doesn't show up in google-chrome.

Comment: You can transpose it to JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ . Makes it an excellent online demo so we can see the behavior and debug. And like gastonfartek said, CSS Reset is a very handy tool to make sure all browsers "start" at the same base.

Comment: I will try to use jsfiddle. To make sure I understand the reset correctly, it is a technique to set the browser to the same settings to begin with? So I should put reset.css in the head before all the other stylesheet, right? This is actually what I did. It doen't change anything to both browsers.

Comment: And by the way, I just tested IE. It works too.

Answer (score 1):

try using a css reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/, if you provide more information on how the page is behaving would be better